# SQL Server DeadLock Error

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have a process that runs on four different servers. This process runs 24h/day non stop. Since the same code is duplicated on 4 different servers, and strike on the same database, this often generates a deadlock error in the database.

The error message in french is the following:

> La transaction (ID de processus 140) a été bloquée sur les ressources verrou par un autre processus et a été choisie comme victime. Réexécutez la transaction

Which roughly translats to:

> Transaction (Process ID 140) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as victim. Rerun the transaction.

I code in ColdFusion, and the SGBD is SQL Server. Does anyone have a solution to avoid this database lock without using `cftransaction`?

Comment: Why "without using `<cftransaction>`? Because that would be how to fix it.

Comment: English translation:  "Transaction (Process ID 140) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as victim. Rerun the transaction."

Comment: The query in question is impportant here and will determine your options. Is it an update or rows? A complex select with joins? An insert? Can you paste in the query please?

Comment: In fact I have a lot of query that generate a lock error. As you said I have an  update query and a complexe select with join. The query is too long, I can not paste it here.

Comment: Without a specific example - folks can only offer general tips. There is really no one-size-fits-all answer for resolving deadlocks. You need to do some research and profiling of your queries. A search for [sql-server deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+deadlock) turns up a number of relevant threads that should get you started.